If an interrupt signal lasts for multiple cycles, will it be processed multiple times in RISC-V?
I am implementing a RISC-V CPU with privilege levels, but I encountered an issue regarding interrupt handling. As a beginner in computer architecture, I would like to ask:

When mstatus.mie is 0, or the corresponding bit in mie is 0, if the CPU receives an interrupt, will the CPU still set the corresponding bit in mip to 1?
Is the interrupt signal sent to the CPU strictly limited to only one cycle?
If not, let's assume there is a device that continuously sends interrupt signals to the CPU until the CPU enters the interrupt handler and responds to the device, then my understanding of the interrupt handling process is as follows:
The CPU receives an interrupt signal -> the corresponding bit in mip is set to 1 -> after the current instruction completes, the CPU starts handling the interrupt, sets mstatus.mie to 0, the corresponding bit in mip to 0, (and other operations), then jumps to mtvec for interrupt handling.
When the CPU starts interrupt handling but has not yet sent the "handled" signal to the device, the device is still sending interrupt signals to the CPU. At this point, if the answer to question (1) is yes, the CPU will still set the corresponding bit in mip to 1. So, when the current exception handling is completed and mret restores mstatus.mie to 1, the CPU will find a 1 in mip, and it seems the CPU will handle this exception again?

I searched online but found no answer. I noticed that in RISC-V manual it says interrupts must be re-evaluated after executing xRET, which I think will lead to an interrupt being handled again after its xRET if mip is set in trap handing proccess.

The hardware collects interrupt requests from various devices and or's them together to set the mip — it does this every cycle.
Devices have to be reset or cleared to acknowledge an interrupt, which should happen during/within the exception handler, and then if no more devices want interrupt service then mip turns off.
Software has to acknowledge a device's interrupt request and that then turns off that device's interrupt request.  This acknowledgement is done by software communicating with the device in some manner, sometimes implicitly by accepting/reading some data, other times by more or less explicitly telling the device its interrupt request has been serviced.
So, it is possible to have two interrupts at the same time, meaning that clearing one device (e.g. during handling) won't turn off mip.  The exception handler can either check mip and choose to re-run itself, or it can simply resume the interrupted code only to have the processor cause another exception immediately.

When mstatus.mie is 0, or the corresponding bit in mie is 0, if the CPU receives an interrupt, will the CPU still set the corresponding bit in mip to 1?

Yes.  Regardless of whether interrupts are off, mip continuously represents an or'ing all the devices' uncleared/unresolved interrupt requests together.

Is the interrupt signal sent to the CPU strictly limited to only one cycle?

No, mip stays set until all interrupt requesting devices have been cleared/reset (i.e. handled).
